# How to design and develop a financial transactions app in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, asynchronous, microservices

I try to make an app for a test and I need some help. The app is about financial transactions and could be 4 transactions type. And I need to do 2 microservices.

The MS2 will have 2 entities:

User entity:

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String tin;
    private String iban;
    private String pocketNo;
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
}
```

Transaction entity:

```
public class Transaction {

    private int id;
    private enum TransactionType {
        IBAN_TO_IBAN, IBAN_TO_POCKET, POCKET_TO_IBAN, POCKET_TO_POCKET;
    }

    private int noOfTransactions;
    private BigDecimal sum;
}
```

Any feedback will be appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple endpoints for multiple transaction types is a better idea as opposed to a single one because it will lead to cleaner code that is much easier to maintain and write tests for.

If you use only one endpoint, you may have to write some parsing logic and add conditions (either `if` or `switch`, both are not ideal) to determine how to handle the transaction in your `RestController`. This additional complexity can introduce bugs and add to your development time, whereas writing 4 separate endpoints removes the unnecessary logic and allows you to focus on writing only what you need.

Having a REST API for report generation is fine too. Just be cautious on what you want the required arguments to be- you might want `id` to be required for report generation, but your API might need to be flexible enough to generate reports from the `iban` or `pocketNo` properties. The annotation `@RequestParam(required = false)` can help with this.

For additional information, the book [Clean Code](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/clean-code/9780136083238/) has a good chapter on writing functions.